# How to map one data set to the bottom-left xy axis and and another to the upper-right xy axis on the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to put together two data sets into the same plot. I want one data set mapped to the bottom-rleft xy axis and the other data set mapped to the upper-right xy axis.

```
# Bottom-Left data set
PCscores <- data.frame(sample = paste("sample",1:10,sep="_"), 
                       PC1 = c(-9,-8,-10,0,1,2,18,20,19,21),
                       PC2 = c(-8,-9,-10,2,0,1,21,19,18,19))


# Upper-Right data set
loadings <- data.frame(snps = letters[1:4], 
                       pc1 = c(0.7,0.8,-0.5,-1), 
                       pc2 = c(0.8,0.7,-1,-0.7),
                       FROM=0,
                       TO=0)
```

If I try to put them together, both data sets are mapped to the bottom-left xy axis.

```
ggplot(data = PCscores, aes(PC1,PC2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(data = loadings, 
               aes(x = FROM, y = TO, xend = pc1, yend = pc2), arrow = arrow())
```

Is this "double" mapping possible to do in `ggplot2`?, if not, base `R` solutions are welcome as well.

Comment: What do you expect this to look like exactly? You want 2 sets of x-axes and 2 sets of y-axes?

Comment: I can't understand the problem. Points are mapped to get coords you provide. What result do you expect? Which dataset should go top/right?

Comment: I would like the arrows to have the same scale as if they were plotted alone ``ggplot(data = loadings) + geom_segment(aes(x = FROM, y = TO, xend = pc1, yend = pc2), arrow = arrow()) + xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) ``

Comment: Thanks! It's clear now

Comment: Can you put actual data using `dput`? Is it much more complicated? Are there samples in top left or bottom right?

Comment: Still collecting it. Basically it will be a PCA but the package does not output a ``princomp`` object, so I cann not apply ``biplot()`` to the data and I have to do it by hand. And yes, samples are present in those two coordinates as well.

Comment: This problem is data specific. What you need to do is to scale loadings. However, scaling factor depends on how your data is distributed. For now I can suggest to multiply it by some integer (judging from your data - try 15): use this within aes `xend = pc1 * 15, yend = pc2 * 15`